# Can someone help me parallelize this C++ Code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

So I've been tasked with finding a way to parallelize this simple C++ problem. The problem is... I'm really... REALLY struggling with parallel programming concepts and have no idea what to do.  The steps to be taken are below:

1) take a positive integer N as an argument
2) create an integer array of size N
3) populate the integers from range [1,1000]
**4) Find the largest integer and the sum of the array in parallel**
5) print the largest integer and the sum of the array.

It was easy enough until I got to step 4. I have no idea how to parallelize this code. I've heard of concepts like threading and multi-threading but I have next to zero idea how to implement them in C++ and could really use some assistance + detailed explanation with this. I have yet to find a concrete example of a  C++ program that has been parallelized that makes sense to me.

```
#include  <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "Enter the Size of the Array (N):  \n ";
int N;
cin >> N;

int array[N];
int largest_number = 0;
int sum = 0;

srand(time(0));
cout << "Populating Array...\n";

//  Filling up the Array  with values
    for(int i =0; i < N; i++)
    {

    array[i] =  (rand() % 1000) + 1;

    }


// Finding the largest value and calculating sum of the array
    for( int j  = 0; j < N; j++)
    {

    sum += array[j];

    if( array[j] > largest_number)
    {largest_number = array[j];}

    }

cout << "Output: \n";
cout << "Maximum:  " <<  largest_number << ";" <<  "Sum: " <<  sum;
cout << "\n";

 }
```

As it stands right now, the code works fine. I just need it to show instances of parallel programming.

As far as expectations go, I could implement a timer on the code to check how much faster parallelization will be on this code but I want to make sure it works first. Thanks

Comment: Maybe have a look at Intel Thread Building Blocks, especially at the _parallel_reduce_ operation.

Comment: I don't think *Find the largest integer and the sum of the array in parallel* is actually asking you to do multithreading.  I believe the requirement is asking you to find the sum of the array, and the max value of the array, in a single pass, thus making the task parallel.

Comment: Also note that `int array[N];` is illegal and if you are using gcc, using `-pedantic-errors` will turn it into a compiler error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For many simple parallel problems, OpenMP is going to be your best choice.

It's already included in all C++ compilers, it's a mature industry standard, it offers capabilities to offload to GPUs, and it's minimally invasive to existing code, allowing you to drop back to a serial formulation easily.

Below, I've rewritten your code to leverage OpenMP. I've also made several other changes.

I've dropped the `using namespace std` line. This line's potentially dangerous because the standard library is *big* and this pulls all of it into the global namespace where it can potentially conflict with other libraries you might be using.

I've also dropped `int array[N]`. This code was dangerous to begin with because arrays like this can only really only be defined if `N` is a compile-time constant. What you really needed was a dynamic allocation. In C++ the best way to do that is with `std::vector` (see below).

Finally, we get to the for-loop. OpenMP works best for scenarios in which each iteration of the loop is *independent*. This means that if you'll have difficulty using it with code like `a[i]=3*a[i-1]`. However, your loop can be made to fit the pattern.

The call to OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) reduction(max:largest_number)
```

tells the computer

> Start as many threads as there are cores and divide the loop evenly between these threads. Give each thread its own *private* copy of the variables `sum` and `largest_number`. Once each thread has finished its work, combine the private `sum` variables into a global `sum` variable using the `+` operator. Also, combine all the private `largest_number` variables into a global `largest_number` variable using the `max` operator.

As you can see, this single line is a very succinct representation of what needs to be done. Even if you're planning on using a more complicated framework, such as Intel's Thread Building Blocks or rolling your own with `std::thread`, OpenMP can be a good way of prototyping a solution. It also plays nicely with TBB and `std::thread`.

```
//Compile with g++ main.cpp -fopenmp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main(){
  std::cout << "Enter the Size of the Array (N): ";
  int N;
  std::cin >> N;

  std::vector<int> array(N);

  //WARNING: This is a poor way of choosing a seed
  srand(time(0));

  std::cout << "Populating Array...\n";
  for(int i =0; i < N; i++)
    array[i] =  (rand() % 1000) + 1; //WARNING: This is a poor way to choose random numbers

  int largest_number = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  // Finding the largest value and calculating sum of the array
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) reduction(max:largest_number)
  for( int j  = 0; j < N; j++){
    sum += array[j];

    if(array[j] > largest_number)
      largest_number = array[j];
  }

  std::cout << "Output: \n";
  std::cout << "Maximum:  " <<  largest_number << ";" <<  "Sum: " <<  sum;
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is really great! Thank you so much for the response. I have one other question for you if you don't mind. What if I wanted to use Clik Plus concepts like clik_spawn, clik_for, or clik_sync for something like this?  The syntax seemed to be a bit easier to understand but I'm still a bit confused how you might implement clik plus on code like this so that someone could compile it like --> g++ main.cpp -fclikplus

Comment: @Caladin00: I'm afraid I don't know Cilk and your question didn't mention it. (If I did know, I'd be happy to try to help you - sorry.) If you want Cilk-specific answers, I'd suggest asking a separate question specifying that up-front. As it is, you're going to get a wide variety of C++ compliant answers.

Comment: That's a fault on my end. Regardless, thank you for your explanation! It made a ton of sense.

Comment: @Richard awesome explanation. does the giving of its own private copy occur because of the `reduction` argument? or is that purely just for aggregation afterwards?
I ask to know whether the variables declared right before the parallelized loop are safe to update by reference within the loop in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: I assume I would have to use the `copyin()` argument to create a copy of any of those variables to the non-master threads?

Answer (score 1):

With C++17 [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce):

```
std::vector<int> array(N);
// ...
const auto sum = std::reduce(std::execution::par, arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
```

Comment: This would be far better with a demonstration / explanation!